# Need a web host that allows MySQL triggers on shared accounts

Tags: mysql, hosting

Does anyone have experience with or know of a web host that allows the use of MySQL triggers on shared (read "cheap") accounts?

I currently use [Surpass Hosting](http://www.surpasshosting.com/) and they told me this was a feature they won't support for security reasons.

**Update**

I've checked with [bluehost](http://www.bluehost.com), [Host Monster](http://www.hostmonster.com), and [DreamHost](http://www.dreamhost.com) and none of them support triggers.

This is all due to triggers requiring the SUPER privilege. MySQL 5.1.6 will implement a TRIGGER privilege, which should alleviate the issue.

Comment: Try asking in serverfault. Voted to close/move.

Comment: Off topic everywhere. Ressource recommendations are a no no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only host I found so far to support mysql triggers on shared packages is <s>[placehost](http://www.placehost.net)</s>

Answer (score 0):

I think most hosts that have mysql 5 or later will support triggers, but i have actually not used them with mysql myself.

Ive use Dreamhost for many years and alwasy been happy with them (http://dreamhost.com or http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?redpirk to give me credits ;)

if you send me short code snippet, i can test.

Comment: I am using dreamhost now, and it does not support triggers on shared accounts, requires SUPER privileges

Comment: OK, me bad. Perhaps you'll need a mysql PS server, should give you enough rights - and a somewhat pricier solution :-P

Comment: I did contact support just to be sure, but even their PS "will not offer me SUPER privileges" :(. Anyway i have a work around already for the application layer

Comment: @dr.stonyhills 

Please tell me your workaround method to avoid triggers and still enforce database rules.

Answer (score 0):

i've used [nativespace.co.uk (affiliate link)](http://tinyurl.com/nvh96s). very helpful service and setup triggers for me even though there wasn't an option to do it on the control panel.
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that namesco did not allow me to set up triggers on their shared hosting package.